# Is it more memory efficient to define and initialize an NSArray when a UIView first loads or only when a condition is met?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it better to initialize an NSArray in viewDidLoad when the program first starts up, or define the NSArray only if a condition is met?

Basically, I initialized an NSArray in an IF condition of one of my methods. This method may be called multiple times, and want to know if it's better on memory if the NSArray is created and destroyed in the method, or if it's better to define it once in viewDidLoad and reference it in the method?

If I'm not clear, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: if you have to use the same array multiple times then create the global reference to it and initialise it in the viewDidLoad or in model class.

Comment: How large your array?

Comment: hi suhit, if you post your comment as an answer, I will accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Create any data collection only when you need it, this way you make sure that the program/screen is initially launched quickly. This is called as lazy loading, this approach should be followed whenever possible.

If you are using NSMutableArray and managing this in run time, you can do something like this for lazy loading, and clearing it from memory when not needed. Add helper methods to add and remove objects from an array, array is created automatically when needed and removed from memory when it is empty.

```
- (void)addObject:(NSObject *)value
{
    if (value == nil) return;

    if (_collection == nil) {
        _collection = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    [_collection addObject:value];
}

- (void)removeObject:(NSObject *)value
{
    if (value == nil) return;

    [_collection removeObject:value];

    if ([_collection count] == 0) {
        [_collection release], _collection = nil;
    }
}
```